# jquery .ajax() method fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with this javascript?

```
        $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

The 'error' event handler function is invoked and this is my console output:

```
error
undefined
XMLHttpRequest { mozResponseArrayBuffer=ArrayBuffer, status=0, more...}
```

I'm trying to learn how to make ajax calls with jquery, and I'm still pretty new to it.

Comment: Have you tried another URL? Like try putting a local file and asking for that. What does Chrome say? And are you trying to do this locally or on a server? (By locally I mean the file:// protocol)

Comment: What is 'textStatus' when you get into the Error block ?

Comment: Try adding `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax... I'm not sure if that'll help but it might :P

Comment: You can't make cross-domain ajax requests without some extra work - you must either use JSONP or the server must allow cross domain requests by way of access-control headers. See my answer for more details and some links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're doing a Cross domain request, which is blocked by your browser.

You could directly use the Maps API, which has convenient methods for such things.

**[Maps Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingRequests)**

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: GMaps API is doing JSONP or html-script requests behind the scene, not "basic" Ajax requests.

Comment: I'm actually not trying to call the google map geocoder api, I was just using a url that I knew would be working. I've also tried to access files within my domain and those have had identical results.

Comment: In the case of using $.ajax with Google Maps API, it's just forbidden, I'm pretty sure you can forget it since "XMLHttpRequest is subject to the browser's same origin policy in that, for security reasons, requests will only succeed if they are made to the same server that served the original web page." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). If you can't do any other request within your domain, please ask a new Question with more details, thanks.

Comment: Here's the return in Chrome:  `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false&_=1305049838758. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: This one confirms what I said (for this case) origin policy = cross domain ajax forbidden by the browser :-)

Comment: NB: I think different subdomains are not allowed for Ajax neither. Be careful about that!

Comment: @Clement They're not and neither are different ports *or* different schemes! So a page loaded with `https` will not be able to make an Ajax request to the same domain and resource but on `http`!

Answer (score 0):

I've just run this block of code through JSFiddle and get the same error problem.

however, when I go directly to the request URL I get this block of JSON:

```
{
  "status": "REQUEST_DENIED",
  "results": [ ]
}
```

Are you getting the same ?

Comment: I think you copied it wrong, I made the same mistake at first but it should pull up valid data.

Comment: That fiddle has `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA`   The OP has this in his question `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false`

Comment: yeah, I removed the &sensor bit testing, it's the same difference though.

Answer (score 0):

- The first problem is that you can't make cross-domain Ajax requests without some extra work - you must use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and not just 'plain' JSON or the server must allow the CDR via the appropriate access-control headers<sup>[**[ref]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control)</sup>.
- However, the bigger problem here is that with v3 of the API, Google has taken away the ability to make JSONP requests (or at least it is undocumented at the moment). They would prefer you to use the [Google Maps library geocoder](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) instead:

  ```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
                  'address': '1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View'
                   },

                   function(data, status){
                        console.log(data); //data is an array of results
                   });
  ```

---

For the moment, you could fall back to the [v2 API](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) if you absolutely *must* have Ajax geocoding but don't want to use the geocoder built into the Google Maps JS library:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,

    url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=json&sensor=false&key=<your_key_here>',

    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data); //geocoded data
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    },

    jsonp: 'callback',

    dataType: 'json'
});
```